# Trying to Write Multiple Files at Once - Java

Tags: java, file-io, dictionary

I am trying to split a dictionary file that I have into multiple dictionaries of different lengths, for example if I want take it and put it into smaller dictionaries of length 2, 3, 4, ..... n, where I can then search them quicker. When I say quicker I mean that I will know the input length and therefore accessing the corresponding length dictionary (a fraction of the whole) will mean quicker accesses. This is my current implementation that generates the files but doesn't write to them like I desire. Ideally, all words of length 2 for example will be written into the length2 text file.  Anyone have any suggestions?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("dictionary.txt");
    PrintWriter l2 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length2.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l3 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length3.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l4 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length4.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l5 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length5.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l6 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length6.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l7 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length7.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l8 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length8.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l9 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length9.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l10 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length10.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l11 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_lengty11.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l12 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length12.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l13 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length13.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l14 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length14.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l15 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length15.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l16 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length16.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l17 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length17.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l18 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length18.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l19 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length19.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l20 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length20.txt", "UTF-8");
    PrintWriter l21 = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length21.txt", "UTF-8");

    BufferedReader tr = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String temp;
    int temp_length;

    for(int i = 0; i < 60388; i++){
        temp = new String(tr.readLine());
        temp_length = temp.length();
        if(temp_length == 2)
            l2.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 3)
            l3.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 4)
            l4.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 5)
            l5.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 6)
            l6.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 7)
            l7.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 8)
            l8.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 9)
            l9.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 10)
            l10.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 11)
            l11.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 12)
            l12.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 13)
            l13.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 14)
            l14.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 15)
            l15.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 16)
            l16.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 17)
            l17.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 18)
            l18.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 19)
            l19.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 20)
            l20.println(temp);
        if(temp_length == 21)
            l21.println(temp);
    }

    tr.close();
    l2.close();
    l3.close();
    l4.close();
    l5.close();
    l6.close();
    l7.close();
    l8.close();
    l9.close();
    l10.close();
    l11.close();
    l12.close();
    l13.close();
    l14.close();
    l15.close();
    l16.close();
    l17.close();
    l18.close();
    l19.close();
    l20.close();
    l21.close();
    System.out.println("Complete.");
}
}
```

Comment: I am making a program that solves jumbles, like in the newspapers. Therefore, it would be quicker to binary search a list that's a fraction of the size of the dictionary rather than the whole thing. Such as if there are seven jumbled characters, I only search the dictionary include seven letter words.

Comment: _"does [not?] write to them like I desire"_ - that's pretty vague. What behavior do you want and how is the actual behavior different?

Comment: so if the word was "apple" for example, it would see that it is length five and write it to the corresponding length 5 text file. However, when I run this, it just generates a bunch of empty files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tangental "answer" follows. (This *should* also print out contents to the files, unless I'm missing something very basic.)

---

Whenever there is a set of variables in the form `xN` (e.g. `l2`, `l3`, `l22`), they should *usually* be replaced with a List collection type such as an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

This is just an example to show *how* can be reduce duplication and fixed bounds:

```
int MAX_WORD_LEN = 22; // making this dynamic left as an excercise
List<PrintWriter> writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();

for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_WORD_LEN; i++) {
    PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter("dictionary_length" + i + ".txt", "UTF-8");
    writers.Add(w);
}

String line;
while ((line = tr.readLine()) != null) {
   int len = line.length();
   if (len < writers.size()) {
       writers.get(len).println(line);
   }
}

for (PrintWriter w : writers) {
    w.close();
}
```

Slight adjustments can be made to not create a "0" or "1" file.

Comment: I had no idea that I had this sort of power in java, saves a ton of typing! Thanks!

Comment: @dsiebert424 i.e `BufferedReader tr = new BufferedReader(fr);`

Comment: I believe that to make it dynamic all I would have to do is have it generate linked lists nodes as it finds a new longest word?

Comment: @dsiebert424 The easy way would be to only `add` to the collection when a new line length is found (for an ArrayList, you'd need to add up to the length but for a HashMap you'd only need to add the new entry). That is, the output files would only be created when a line of the particular length was first found.