# Having a variable from another class as the file name (GUI)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

One class of my GUI has a variable for the file name. I want to pass this to another class so that I can process a file without having to hard code the file's name every time. The program compiles fine but I can't seem to run it correctly.

```
public void run() {
  WordsCounter2 fileName = new WordsCounter2();
  essayName = fileName.getFileList();
    File f = new File(essayName);
    //other code
```

WordsCounter2 is the class that houses the variable fileName, I'm calling it from this class and assigning it as the file's name, but this doesn't work. Could someone help?

```
     if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File[] selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
        fileList = "nothing";
        if (selectedFile.length > 0) 
           fileList = selectedFile[0].getName();
        for (int i = 1; i < selectedFile.length; i++) {
           fileList += ", " + selectedFile[i].getName();
        }
        statusBar.setText("You chose " + fileList);
     }
     else {
        statusBar.setText("You didn't choose a file.");
     }
```

fileList isn't empty because I have a label on the GUI that lists whatever file I chose.

Here's my new edit: now the exception occurs at the last line with the scanner and throws a NPE. Can you help?

```
public void run() {
  WordsCounter2 pathNamesList = new WordsCounter2();
  essayName = pathNamesList.getPathNamesList();
  essayTitle = new String[essayName.size()];
  essayTitle = essayName.toArray(essayTitle);
  for (int i = 0; i < essayTitle.length; i++) {
       f = new File(essayTitle[i]);
  }
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
```

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting to the post? Also adding code for the WordsCounter2.getFileList() will be helpful.

Comment: The code is as follows:

Comment: public WordsCounter2(String fileList) {
      this.fileList = fileList;
   }
   
   public String getFileList() {
      return fileList;
   }

Comment: So perhaps the fileList value is simply empty? You never initialized it via the constructor.

Comment: I have edited my question to show that fileList isn't empty.

Comment: So from the looks of it, fileList holds comma separated names of selected files. To create a new file, you need to give a path name.

Comment: Wouldn't the path name be specific for each file, and thus I have to input a different one every time?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because File will not accept comma separated file names, in fact, it needs a single file path to create the file in the mentioned path. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

You'll have to get complete paths in an array and put the file creation statement as follows:

```
File f;
for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++)
    f = new File(fileList[i]);
```

where fileList is a String array holding the list of pathnames.

In case you're trying to write some content to these files as well, this should be helpful: [Trying to Write Multiple Files at Once - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447097/trying-to-write-multiple-files-at-once-java)